# Вставка многомерного массива построчно в таблицу

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Есть таблица 
user_id | role1_id | role2_id

Массив ARRAY[[1,2],[3,4]]

Как вставить в таблицу данные из массива? Что бы получилось так:

user_id | 1 | 2
user_id | 3 | 4

Comment: С чем возникли проблемы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Затруднение видимо вызвало вот такое поведение штатной функции `unnest`:

```
select * from unnest(ARRAY[[1,2],[3,4]]);
 unnest 
--------
      1
      2
      3
      4
(4 строки)
```

[В стандартной поставке](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) не наблюдаю другой подходящей функции. Значит давайте её напишем:

```
create or replace function unnest_dim(in_array anyarray) 
returns setof anyarray as $$ 
    declare el in_array%type;
    begin 
        foreach el slice 1 in array in_array
        loop 
            return next el;
        end loop;
    end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Получили развернутый на одно измерение меньше массив:

```
select * from unnest_dim(ARRAY[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]);
 unnest_dim 
------------
 {1,2}
 {3,4}
 {5,6}
(3 строки)
```

Теперь можно записать в таблицу простым запросом (на примере `user_id` 15):

```
insert into users (user_id, role1_id, role2_id) 
select 15, r[1], r[2] 
    from unnest_dim(ARRAY[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]) as r;
```